# How to override log level at an app level

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, scala-logging

Have a common spark cluster with log level set to error, Unable to override the log level at an App level..

Using

```
"com.typesafe.scala-logging" %%  "scala-logging" % Versions.typesafeScalaLoggingVersion,
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % Versions.chQosLogbackClassicVersion
```

In the App,

```
object BillingdataApp extends LazyLogging {
logger.info(s"Does not log")
logger.error(s"This logs")}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works..

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger
Logger.getLogger("com").setLevel(Level.INFO)
```